# Binding cannot contain Assignments

Tags: typescript, angular8

I'm trying to get WareHouse Name from a list using its Id and populate the same in a table

```
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let data of sectionList;index as i">
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td>{{data.sectionName}}</td>              
        <td>{{wareHouseList.find(x=>x.Id == data.WareHouseId).wareHouseName}}</td>
        <td>{{data.DestinationWareHouseId}}</td>            
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

But i keep getting this error in Console,Is is the correct way to include statements in typescript?

```
Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 22 in [{{wareHouseList.find(x=>x.Id == data.WareHouseId).sectionName}}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{{ }} means a binding.You can't use like that.

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let data of sectionList;index as i">
      <td>{{i+1}}</td>
      <td>{{data.sectionName}}</td>              
      <td>{{ returnPicked(data.WareHouseId) }}</td>
      <td>{{data.DestinationWareHouseId}}</td>            
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

In your ts ->

```
public returnPicked(warhouseId): string {
  return wareHouseList.find(x=>x.Id == warhouseId).wareHouseName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... but the table does not validate the expression.It simply prints the code

Comment: Thanks,the issue is sorted.